# What is the coordinate system in MDriven (browser location)

Tags: mdriven

What is the coordinate system for the values obtained in MDriven ViewModel variables (vLatitude and vLongitude)?

Comment: Should be vClientLongitude and vClientLatitude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates from the Angular html5 web client for MDriven are taken from the browser like this:

```
<script>
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
       function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
    }
    </script>
```

The coordinates are floating point numbers